# react native - gif loads very slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a react native app with expo

I am trying to display some gifs in my app, everything is working great when I am running it on my simulator but on an actual device the gif loads after a very long time

I minified the gifs but the problem still continues

everyone familiar with this problem and knows how to solve it?

Comment: What about images? Images getting uploaded fine?

Comment: yes images loaded fine